# Bosch Nexxt 100 Washer wires damaged while replacing motor brushes

Tags: repair, appliances

I have a Bosch Nexxt 100 washer, model WFMC1001UC. The carbon brushes in the motor need replacing every so often, which is relatively easy. However, this time, while removing the motor from the machine, one of the cable plugs that connects 3 blue wires to the motor came apart, resulting in the 3 wires being released from the plug and the plug remaining on the header. I'd like to be able to repair the plug by placing the wires back on, but I don't know which wire goes where and am not sure about how much risk there is in trying different combinations. I also don't know how to identify this particular wire assembly to order a replacement part. It seems to connect to (what I conclude is) the motor control board. There's a similar 3 wire blue plug there, but I don't know if I can just match the alignment of the 3 wires (i.e. left, middle, right) to the plug on the motor.

Is there a simple, safe way for me to repair this plug, or can anyone help me identify this assembly so I can replace it?

[image: The broken plug]
[image: The corresponding? plug on the motor control board]

Comment: "not sure about how much risk there is in trying different combinations" There is probably a great risk if the voltage on the wires is plug-in house voltage, which is possible considering the warning label on the unit. Even if low voltage, if the circuit was not designed with proper protection, random testing of the wiring connection could let out the magic smoke. Sensors being connected incorrectly can cause the washer to run incorrectly. I have found wiring diagrams inside my washers and dryers, inside the control panel. Or a diagram may be found in a web-search.

Comment: There's no diagram inside the machine that I can see and I couldn't find anything online except for very low-resolution exploded part diagrams that don't adequately explain what the wiring parts are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a chance - I used a meter to test connectivity between the wires in the grey plug next to the blue plug and found that, if we number the wires 1-9, they all corresponded in the same order between the motor control board and the motor. So I traced which wires were the 7,8,9 in the blue plug and positioned those to match at the other end, re-assembled the plug, and re-assembled the machine (incidentally, I had to file-down the sides of the carbon brushes to let them fit loosely in their slots so that the spring could allow them to touch the motor).

The machine appears to work now.